# Getting the Server URL in Google App Engine using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, web-applications

How do I get App Engine to generate the URL of the server it is currently running on?

If the application is running on development server it should return

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

and if the application is running on Google's servers it should return

```
http://application-name.appspot.com
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the URL that was used to make the current request from within your webapp handler via `self.request.url` or you could piece it together using the `self.request.environ` dict (which you can read about on the [WebOb docs](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#id1) - request inherits from webob)

You can't "get the url for the server" itself, as many urls could be used to point to the same instance.

If your aim is really to just discover wether you are in development or production then use:

```
'Development' in os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
```

Comment: +1 For trying to guess at actual intent and letting him know about the dev server flag.

Comment: `self.request.host` is a better way to get just the current hostname, or `self.request.host_url` if you want the protocol prefix.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an alternative answer.

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
server_url = app_identity.get_default_version_hostname()
```

On the dev appserver this would show:

> localhost:8080

and on appengine

> your_app_id.appspot.com

Comment: Google seems to have depreciated this for python 3 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.app_identity

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **webapp2** as framework chances are that you already using URI routing in you web application.
http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/', handler=HomeHandler, name='home'),
])
```

When building URIs with `webapp2.uri_for()` just pass `_full=True` attribute to generate absolute URI including current domain, port and protocol according to current runtime environment.

```
uri = uri_for('home')
# /

uri = uri_for('home', _full=True)
# http://localhost:8080/
# http://application-name.appspot.com/
# https://application-name.appspot.com/
# http://your-custom-domain.com/
```

This function can be used in your Python code or directly from templating engine (if you register it) - very handy.

Check [webapp2.Router.build()](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Router.build) in the API reference for a complete explanation of the parameters used to build URIs.